# Using Mongo Motor with async create_task

Tags: python, mongodb, python-asyncio

I want to submit data to MongoDB in a non-blocking way. Other questions on this website recommend either:

1. Phrasing this problem as a single-producer, single-consumer problem with queue communication.
2. Using Motor with `asyncio` and `create_task`.

All examples [in the Motor documentation](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html) use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` and `run_until_complete()`. However, this is a *blocking* way of running co-routines. I would like to instead use the *non-blocking* method of `create_task`.

Here's what I've tried:

```py
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(my_login_url)

async def do_find_one():
    doc = client.my_db.my_collection.find_one()
    pprint.pprint(doc)

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(do_find_one())

    print("other things")
    await task
    print("done")

asyncio.run(main())
```

However, instead of a MongoDB entry, `task` just prints a pending Future which I don't know how to get the value of. How am I supposed to be using `motor` with `create_task`?

Comment: `do_find_one` doesn't return a value.

Comment: I say "returns" but I meant "print". I'll edit the question. However, it is possible, there are multiple levels of confusion happening here.

Comment: If the problem is that `doc` doesn't have the value you're expecting, maybe you need to await `find_one`. If that doesn't help, perhaps you can tell us what the expected output is and what the actual output is.

Comment: if find_one is a coroutine then you need to await it.  If it's not a coroutine then it's just a regular function, and there is no point in trying to use it with asyncio.